# Mastering a foreign language without staying in a country to which the language is native

Tags: language-acquisition, second-lang-acquisition

I am not a native English speaker. What I would like to understand is - if a non native speaker who’s got a fairly decent command on the language (in this case say English) speaks to his or her kid in English, would it increase their kids grasp on English and the ability to comprehend the language better. In essence, does interacting with kids in a foreign language increase the kid’s grasp on a foreign language?  I understand accent, pronunciation, modulation, intonation all these aspects play an important role but my question is primarily about the usage, and by that I mean the usage of words, grammar, phrases, idioms.

I would like to add one more parameter,  If the family is not resident in a native English speaking country, and in future if the kid travels to an English speaking country would they be able to seamlessly integrate into the English speaking community (nothing to do with cultural values, in this context), and would their ability to comprehend, read, write and speak be as good  OR nearly as good as the native speakers. Have you come across such cases wherein someone mastered a foreign language even without  staying in the country to which the language is native?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Linguistics. Unfortunately, the topic of this site is not about learning/teaching process. Instead, it's about natural characteristics of languages. There are some aspects of languages that impact learning process, but most certainly you won't find a good answer right here. You may try [Academia@SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) but please double-check what topics are good there. Yet another thing, StackExchange (with all its sites) **is not a forum**. Try to ask questions that assume a single answer. Look around what questions are asked, check FAQ, etc.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about linguistics within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would teach the language to the kid, but you would have to be very systematic about talking to him/her in the language, which can be difficult if it's not your native language. You would have to set a specific time frame, like one day a week that you only use English. I knew a Hungarian girl, whose bilingual Hungarian father only spoke to her in French, because he wanted her to be bilingual as well. She actually acquired it at near native level and never lived in France. She went on to study French and Spanish at the University.